# Is defining all flux action types in a constants object is a common practice?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flux, reactjs-flux

The question is based upon [the article](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/getting-started-with-the-flux-architecture-in-react--cms-28906?ec_unit=translation-info-language) about flux.

> A common practice is to define all action types in a constants object and reference that object instead across the application to maintain consistency.

What does a common practice mean? I mean why does the author decide it's a common practice? What is it based on? What is **the truth source**? And what if I decided to use action type in lower case?

Comment: It basically means that developers came up with some kind of convention which is there to help in development and maintenance.

Answer (score 1):

Flux is a design pattern, not a specific library or implementation. This pattern helps working with *states* when an app grows in size and complexity.

E.g: Consider an app for managing email, when clicking an email we will have the follow *states* changes:

- Replace the "inbox view" (the list of emails) with the "email view".
- Mark the email as read locally
- Reduce the total unread counter locally
- Change the URL of the browser
- Send a web request to mark the email as read on the server

The function in the top-level component that handles a user clicking on an email must describe all of the *state* changes that occur. This loads a single function with lots of complexity and responsibility.

Redux, one concept of Flux, has the follow key ideas to solve the problem:

- All of your application’s data is in a single data structure called the *state* which is held in the store.
- Your app reads the *state* from this store.
- The *state* is never mutated directly outside the store.
- The views emit actions that describe what happened.
- A new *state* is created by combining the old *state* and the action by a function called the reducer.

The **Store** is a object that held all - or at least most - *states* in the app. It will be created and instantiated in the top-level component. It instance will be accessed by all children components.

Look how similar the **Store** concept is with your citation:

> "... define all action types in a constants object and reference that
>   object instead across the application to maintain consistency."

Comment: Thanks. I see your post as an attempt to showcase some knowledge instead of just to give an answer. You did not give it at all.

Comment: Another convenient use for it is that you can have long, descriptive, unlikely-to-be-duplicated strings for each action, while re-using certain calls as needed.

It's intuitive to know what 'store1Actions.add' is, and you can still say 'store2Actions.add,' but if you were smart with actual value of the add attribute, you don't have to worry about overlap. I tend to make my actions extra long just to avoid potential overlap, as that's such an annoying problem. Something like "ADD_A_VALUE_TO_STORE_NUMBER_1"